# Magento : Display order number below the ordered product image whille printing

Tags: php, magento

I am working on e-commerce site to purchase iphone case online and customers can upload and customize image.

So that in magento admin panel I am converting that product image to jpg and saving. But I want to display Order number on below the image while printing so that in printed image I Can print image with order number.

My jQuery code is:

```
jQuery.post('https://'+window.location.hostname+'/artmanager/index/pngtojpg',{imagedata:img}).done(
    function(data)
    {
            jimg=data;                  
            window.open(data);
            jQuery("#loading-image").hide();
    });
```

My controller code is:

```
public function pngtojpgAction()  
    {       
        //Code to convert png to jpg image
        $input = imagecreatefrompng($this->getRequest()->getParam('imagedata'));
        $width=imagesx($input);
        $height=imagesy($input);
        $output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $white = imagecolorallocate($output,  255, 255, 255);
        imagefilledrectangle($output, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
        imagecopy($output, $input, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);


        $mypath=Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/custom_product_preview/predefined_images/temporary_processing/test.jpg' ;//Saving file as temporary file        

        imagejpeg($output,$mypath,100); 



        $filename = $mypath; //Reading the temporary file           

        // Get new sizes
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $newwidth = 3056;
        $newheight = 4861;

        // Load
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

        // Resize
        imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($thumb);
        $contents =  ob_get_contents();         
        $contents = substr_replace($contents, pack("cnn", 1, 72, 72), 13, 5);   //Converting Image DPI to 72DPI                 
        ob_end_clean();     
        echo 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($contents);        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `imagestring` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php)

```
imagestring($image, $font, $x, $y, $string, $color);
```

`$image` would be `$input`

`$font` is an integer between 1 and 5 (some built-in fonts).

`$x` can be 10 for some basic padding or `$width / 2 - $widthOfImageString / 2` to center it.

`$y` can be `$height - 20` to put it at the bottom.

`$string` would be your order ID (or the increment ID)

`$color` has to be a color identifier created with [imagecolorallocate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php).

Comment: Yes trackbacks, i flag your answer as "Accepted"